# Is it possible to reassign a contribution linked to a membership?

Tags: civimember, contributions

I had a member sign up for an annual membership while their current membership was still active, but they used a slightly different address and so it created a duplicate contact with a new membership. I merged the two contacts and so now I have one contact record with two memberships. I want to keep the older membership and delete the newer one, so I manually renewed the older one. However, deleting the newer one will delete the contribute record associated with that membership.

How can I reassign that contribution, or at least remove the link between the contribution and the newer membership, so that I can delete that membership?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Through UI its bit difficult(impossible). If its a matter of single record then i would suggest you to use API explorer to do it.

Navigate to CiviCRM >> Support >> Developer >> API Explorer

1. Create Membership payment for old membership (23 is old membership id(without contribution) and 45 is contribution id)
   [image]
2. Delete new membership.

> Note: Backup db before performing any api actions

Comment: Thanks! I haven't done any work with the API before but this seems like a good chance to learn.

Answer (score 3):

Pradeep's answer is good if this is a one-off situation.  If you think you might encounter this on an ongoing basis, the [Link Membership to Contributions](https://github.com/CiviCooP/org.civicoop.membershippayment) extension is designed precisely for this.  CiviCoop produced several [useful extensions for administering membership payments](https://civicrm.org/blog/jaapjansma/useful-membership-extensions) including this one.